# Django Rest Framework Error HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed method GET

Tags: django-rest-framework

I try to GET data from model but it show error:

Category List

GET /catalog/

HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

Allow: OPTIONS

Content-Type: application/json

Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}

---

views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import OcCategory
from .serializers import  OcCategorySerializer

class CategoryListView(APIView):
    def get_category_list(self, request):
        category_list = OcCategory.objects.filter(parent_id=0)
        serializer = OcCategorySerializer(category_list, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import OcCategory

class OcCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OcCategory
        fields = ('category_id', 'image', 'parent_id', 'top', 'column', 'sort_order', 'status', 'date_added', 'date_modified','tiu_id','place')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.CategoryListView.as_view()),
]
```

What's wrong?

Comment: could you share your urls.py for /catalog/? probably if you change your method name get_category_list() to get() it will be done.

Comment: thanks) I shared urls.py for /catalog. You are right, with get() it is done! Why it not working with get_category_list()? what's difference?

Answer (score 0):

For APIView class incoming request is dispatched to an appropriate handler method such as .get() or .post().

```
class CategoryListView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pass

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        pass
```